# RAM consumption too high for vector allocation under R

Tags: r, vector, size

I have difficulty under R with a problem, apparently quite common "cannot allocate vector size XXX GB".

In my case there are two procedures, one with a failure on a vector of 1.1 GB and the other on a vector of 4.8 GB

I work on following hardware resources : Windows 10 PC with an 8-core processor (Xeon E5-1620 v4 3.50 Ghz) and 16 GB of RAM and I use R 3.5.0 - 64 bits.

... I did not imagine that my problem could be due to hardware resource for a "small" 1.1 GB vector

I went through the net and tried several solutions (memory.limit, - min-vsize, R_MAX_VSIZE, - max-ppsize, high priority and execution of R as administrator ...) but nothing helps .

So I tried to understand where the problem came from:

```
*> gcinfo(TRUE)
[1] TRUE
> myBiomodData <- BIOMOD_FormatingData(resp.var = myResp,
+                                      expl.var = myExpl,
+                                      resp.xy = myRespXY,
+                                      resp.name = myRespName,
+                                      PA.nb.rep = 1,
+                                      PA.nb.absences = 5000,
+                                      PA.strategy = 'random',
+                                      PA.dist.min = ,
+                                      PA.dist.max = ,
+                                      na.rm=TRUE)
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= BarBar Data Formating -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
      ! No data has been set aside for modeling evaluation
   > Pseudo Absences Selection checkings...
   > random pseudo absences selection
   > Pseudo absences are selected in explanatory variablesGarbage collection 1459 = 967+228+264 (level 0) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
379.5 Mbytes of vectors used (38%)
Garbage collection 1461 = 968+228+265 (level 0) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
482.3 Mbytes of vectors used (61%)
Garbage collection 1462 = 969+228+265 (level 0) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
659.6 Mbytes of vectors used (84%)
Garbage collection 1463 = 969+228+266 (level 2) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
189.1 Mbytes of vectors used (24%)
...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
5002.4 Mbytes of vectors used (42%)
Garbage collection 1777 = 1122+288+367 (level 2) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
5002.4 Mbytes of vectors used (35%)
Garbage collection 1778 = 1122+288+368 (level 2) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
9968.1 Mbytes of vectors used (56%)
Garbage collection 1779 = 1122+288+369 (level 2) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
9968.1 Mbytes of vectors used (56%)
Garbage collection 1780 = 1122+288+370 (level 2) ...
160.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
14933.8 Mbytes of vectors used (69%)

Erreur : impossible d'allouer un vecteur de taille 1.1 Go

> myBiomodData
Erreur : objet 'myBiomodData' introuvable

>gc(TRUE)
Garbage collection 1781 = 1122+288+371 (level 2) ...
160.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
36.7 Mbytes of vectors used (0%)
          used  (Mb) gc trigger    (Mb)   max used    (Mb)
Ncells 3003244 160.4    5651730   301.9    3838487   205.0
Vcells 4801284  36.7 1880774788 14349.2 1957396291 14933.8
```

What I understand is that the resources allocated to the process are already at max (memory.size (max = TRUE) returns 15290.12 MB, without even the changes of environment variables R_MAX and others for that matter): the process crashes at 14 933.8 MB is almost 15GB -> +/- all the RAM available on my computer of 16GB of RAM with the other processes in progress (Windows etc), but they are not enough to create the vector of 1.1 Go (that plants at 69%)

My question is therefore: why R uses a little more than 20GB of RAM (if 69% = 15GB) to allocate a vector of 1.1 GB? And is there a solution other than hardware and physical (add 16GB of RAM to my computer) to get around this problem?

Comment: I interpret this as R uses already 14933.8 MB and has no space for an **additional** vector with 1.1 GB.